# rails options_for_select update form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, erb

This is my biblios_helper.rb:

```
def main_language
    [["français","frenchLit"],["latin","latinLit"],["ancien français","froLit"],["néerlandais","dutchLit"]]
end
```

the form for adding a new bibliography contains :

```
<%= f.select(:langue_main) do %>
    <% options_for_select(main_language, selected: params[:biblio] ? params[:biblio][:langue_main] :"") %>
<% end %>
```

This results in this html :

```
<select name="biblio[main_language]" id="biblio_main_language"><option value="frenchLit">français</option>
<option value="latinLit">latin</option>
<option value="froLit">ancien français</option>
<option value="dutchLit">néerlandais</option></select>
```

That works fine. However, I have the same code in the form that allows for the updating of the bibliography.

when in the database, the language is 'froLit', I want the default to show up in the select menu to be 'ancien français'. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

On edit form it will automatically select the corresponding option as default which options is saved in database for this object -

```
<%=f.select :langue_main, options_for_select(main_language) %>
```

However if you want to be default selected as always to be `["ancien français","froLit"]` Then try this one -

```
<%=f.select :langue_main, options_for_select(main_language, "froLit") %>
```

Comment: No, I want that the corresponding language in the database is selected per default. So if in the database it is 'latinLit', the option should show 'latin' and if the database contains the value 'frenchLit' the option should be 'français'. I have updated the question by adding the html that is generated.

Comment: @thiebo Exactly i've added both the way to do in given answer. can you try the first one. Thanks. also feel free to upvote/accept answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

maybe just:

```rb
= f.select :langue_main, options_for_select(main_language, params.dig(:biblio, :langue_main))
```